# UWP desktop application to access storage account

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to build a native UWP desktop application for uploading and downloading data to the azure blobs. I have registered the application following [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-app?tabs=dotnet), and I acquired the clientID and tenantID. I have also granted permission for the app to Azure Storage.

I cannot put the clientSecret in the application as it can lead to potential threats.

What should be my next step to acquire an access token?
(Any help is really appreciated...)

Answer (score 0):

Please **note** that, if you are using **client credentials** flow, **`client_secret`** is mandatory to get the token.

***I tried to reproduce the same via Postman and got below results:***

I created one Azure AD application and granted permission for the application to **Azure Storage** like below:

[image]

When I did not include **`client_secret`** using **client credentials flow**, I got error like below:

[image]

Alternatively, you can make use of ***ROPC flow*** if you don't want to include **`client_secret`** by enabling below option:

[image]

I generated access token successfully without including **`client_secret`** using ***ROPC flow*** like below:

```json
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:44xxxx450-xxxx-4be1-axxb-e7xxxxxxxx
grant_type:password
scope:https://storage.azure.com/.default
username:user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
password:xxxxxxxxx
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: This is very promising. Thank you so much!
I am able to get the access_token when I am using the client_secret.
Can you suggest how can DefaultCredential() pickup this access_token in .net c#?